# Repositioned button text not clickable

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, css-position

I've created a button that looks like a document with a label below it by moving the button's text outside of its self with `position absolute`:

```js
$('.item-title').hover(function() {
  $(this).parent().addClass('hover');
}, function() {
  $(this).parent().removeClass('hover');
});
$('.item-title').on('click', function() {
  alert('test this')
});
```

```css
.item-button {
  position: relative;
  width: 110px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #eee;
  border: #fff solid 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  margin: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.item-button:hover {
  color: black;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff;
  border: #fff solid 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #999;
}

.hover {
  color: black;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff;
  border: #fff solid 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #999;
}

.item-title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 160px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10pt;
  line-height: 15px;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="item-button"><span class="item-title">File Title</span></button>
```

However I can't seem to get the label that's now floating outside the control to react at all to any mouse events. How can I get it to be clickable and pass its hover state back to its parent?

**Edit**: Seems this is a browser specific issue to firefox, works correctly in Chrome and IE.

Comment: Works fine here though, you mean hovering over the text to initiate the glow on the document right?

Comment: Correct, which in turn would let me see how to let it be clickable as well.

Comment: Weird, right click on the text and “inspect element” puts the focus in the Inspector panel directly on the body element ... looks like a Firefox bug to me. Maybe you can work around that if you don’t position the span absolutely - and insert a second element into the button to create the gray shape (so that the label can go below it without having to resort to absolute positioning, which seems to be the root cause of the issue here.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to write "e.stoppropagation()" in the click event of the label. this will stop the label to push events to its parents.

Update: I tried binding a click event to your label and it works without an issue,

```
$('.item-title').on('click',function(){
alert('test this')});
```

Comment: This doesnt provide an answer to the question

Comment: This has made me realise this is a Firefox specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your Css code :

```
.item-button {
            position: relative;
            width: 110px;
            height: 150px;
            background: #eee;
            border: #fff solid 2px;
            box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
            transition: all 0.5s ease;
            margin: 25px;
            margin-bottom: 40px;
            z-index : 888;

        }
        .item-button:hover {
                color: black;
                text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff;
                border: #fff solid 2px;
                box-shadow: 0 0 20px #999;
        }
        .hover {
                color: black;
                text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff;
                border: #fff solid 2px;
                box-shadow: 0 0 20px #999;
        }

        .item-title {
            position: absolute;
            top: 160px;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 10pt;
            line-height: 15px;
            z-index: 999;
        }
```